# change file size without losing quallity iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, cocoa

I have a image upload app for iOS. It works but 1 problem which I couldn't find.

When you select a photo from the photolib the file size is +- 100kb but if you use your camera and make a picture the file size is a few MB. How can I change the file size without losing quallity or without changing the size of the image?

Comment: By using lossless compression, perhaps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a way to keep the same size while just losing imperceptible quality.

Use:

```
UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.6);
```

You can increase quality and size by increasing from 0.6 to 0.8 etc. (As long as it's a value between 0 and 1)

I believe that the camera roll does this for you, which is why they are in the 100kb range already.

Comment: Thank you it uploads 10 times faster now.